# Python logging creates multiple logs

Tags: python, logging

So I am trying to log some information across multiple modules, and I set up a logger, but it logs everything twice. I have researched this for a little while, and the main suggestion was to add a getLogger('something') to each module I log from. I will implement it that way if I must, but am looking for a way (if one exists) to create the logger once in my main module, and pass it to the other modules (hopefully via import).

This is how I create my logger in **init**.py,

```
formatter = logging.Formatter("[%(asctime)s] {%(module)s:%(lineno)d} (levelname)s - %(message)s")
file_handler = logging.FileHandler('example.log')
file_handler.setLevel(logging.INFO)
file_handler.setFormatter(formatter)
app.logger.addHandler(file_handler)
```

My other modules currently import, and call it as follows,

```
from __init__ import app
app.logger.info("message test")
```

Comment: What do you mean "it logs everything twice"?

Comment: if I did app.logger.info("message test"), my log file would look like
[2016-03-01 16:58:38,755] {module.py:100} INFO message
[2016-03-01 16:58:38,755] {module.py:100} INFO message

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`__init__.py`:

```
import logging

formatter = logging.Formatter("[%(asctime)s] {%(module)s:%(lineno)d} (levelname)s - %(message)s")
file_handler = logging.FileHandler('example.log')
file_handler.setLevel(logging.INFO)
file_handler.setFormatter(formatter)

logger = logging.getLogger('app')
logger.addHandler(file_handler)
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)

logger.info('Logger initialized')
```

`app.py`:

```
from __init__ import logger

logger.info('message test')
```

contents of `example.log` after running app.py **once**:

```
[2016-03-01 20:03:01,364] {__init__:12} (levelname)s - Logger initialized
[2016-03-01 20:03:01,364] {app:3} (levelname)s - message test
```

contents of `example.log` after running app.py again:

```
[2016-03-01 20:03:01,364] {__init__:12} (levelname)s - Logger initialized
[2016-03-01 20:03:01,364] {app:3} (levelname)s - message test
[2016-03-01 20:03:12,034] {__init__:12} (levelname)s - Logger initialized
[2016-03-01 20:03:12,034] {app:3} (levelname)s - message test
```

Does this help?

Comment: Unfortunately on mine it still logs twice. And the logger.info('Logger initialized') somehow gets called 9 times (I have a lot of modules I'm using)

Comment: Ok, well I have no idea why your code is logging multiple times. Maybe you can update the original question to have a self-consistent example that does this double logging or post your code that does this multiple logging on github.

Comment: I doubt I can post an example that emulates what is happening to me, and I can't upload it to github. Thanks for the help though.

Answer (score 0):

logging.conf

```
[loggers]
keys=root,main

[logger_root]
level=DEBUG
handlers=consoleHandler

[logger_main]
level=DEBUG
qualname=main
handlers=fileHandler
#####################handlers#########################
[handlers]
keys=consoleHandler,fileHandler

[handler_consoleHandler]
class=StreamHandler
level=DEBUG
formatter=fmt
args=(sys.stdout,)

#10M-->10*1024*1024,append mod,5-->5 pcs
[handler_fileHandler]
class=logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler
level=DEBUG
formatter=fmt
args=('info.log','a',10*1024*1024,5,)
######################formatters#########################
[formatters]
keys=fmt

[formatter_fmt]
format= %(asctime)s %(filename)s[line:%(lineno)d] -loggername:%(name)s- %(levelname)s --> %(message)s
datefmt=
################################################
```

you script:

```
import logging
import logging.config
logging.config.fileConfig('logging.conf')
logger = logging.getLogger("main")

logger.debug('This is debug message')
logger.info('This is info message')
logger.warning('This is warning message')
logger.error('this is error message')
logger.critical('this critical')
```